# PHP - what is the function to turn $ sign to %24 or any other special character?

Tags: php

`htmlspecialchars` won't do it and neither does `htmlentities`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
urlencode()
```

> Returns a string in which all
>   non-alphanumeric characters except -_.
>   have been replaced with a percent (%)
>   sign followed by two hex digits and
>   spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It
>   is encoded the same way that the
>   posted data from a WWW form is
>   encoded, that is the same way as in
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   media type. This differs from the »
>   RFC 1738 encoding (see rawurlencode())
>   in that for historical reasons, spaces
>   are encoded as plus (+) signs.

http://php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 1):

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Answer (score 1):

urlencode()

[docs](https://www.php.net/urlencode)